# Issues with converting Keras model to TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Python:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import lite
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(filepath) # Your model's name
model = converter.convert()
file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ) 
file.write( model )
```

Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-4a1e951d08b6> in <module>
      1 from tensorflow.contrib import lite
----> 2 converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(filepath)
      3 model = converter.convert()
      4 file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' )
      5 file.write( model )

ValueError: Unknown metric function:top_2_accuracy
```

I have three outputs accuracy which is `top_cat_accuracy`, `top_2_accuracy`, and `top_3_accuracy`. How to solve this?